# WordPress WooCommerce disable email notifications

Tags: wordpress, email, woocommerce, notifications

I'm using WooCommerce in my WordPress website.

I want to disable email notification for processing order.

When I go to `WooCOmmerce > Settings > Emails > Processing orders`, I can unckeck `Enable this email notification`.

But when I save changes, it seems that the changes are not saved. I canno disable any of thoses email notifications.

When I refresh the page, all the email notifications are still enabled. I have no error message.

- I'm using WordPress 4.8.2 with Kallyas theme.
- WooCommerce version 3.1.2.
- WPML Multilingual CMS Version 3.0.1
- WPML Media Version 2.1.1

Comment: do you have any other issue with other settings ? are you able to change other settings ? you when you save the setting open you console and see you there is some errors logged there

Comment: I've solved my problem by completely removing WPML and reinstalling it.

Answer (score 0):

I've solved my problem by completely removing WPML and reinstalling it.